# php script execution timeout

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am creating an application to produce a graph using PHP, highcharts and MySQL.

There are two pages. The first page is for inputting fields from the users and area for produce charts.

In the second page I perform all the calculations for the graph which is to be called through an AJAX call.

I want to have 90 plots in a single graph so there are 90 individual MySQL select statements.

Each MySQL query returns around 100 or 150 records.

The problem is that by the time the script completes execution it is getting timed out. How can I optimize this?

Comment: Can you post your SQL queries to see if there's a way to simplify rather than make 90 calls?

Comment: hello.. thanks for reply. Actually we can't simply the Select statement because what was the client requirement is when the select date range in between one month, i want to divide that date range into 90 range like from 1st one to 2nd one then 2nd one to 3rd one and so on till 90 range. **SELECT `status` FROM `globstats_graph` WHERE `moddate` between '$init_1' and '$total_array[$i]' and `Cname`='$client' and `IP`='$ip' and `Port`='$port' and `Variable`='$var' and status REGEXP '^[0-9]+$|^ON$'**. Already variable column was indexed. For speed up process i have added index in cname column also.

Answer (score 1):

you have change the execution time of your script
so you have put following line in your starting of script

> ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); // 300 sec

Comment: hi,,, I have added the following line in my starting of script ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); even though still i am facing the same problem(timed out). I have one doubt 300 sec is 5 min is it? but my script doesn't execute till 5 min. It was timed out with in 2 min. is there any problem in AJAX call time out?

Comment: increase the _time limit_ in  **php.ini** file and then test again. i think it will help you

Comment: I have increased max_execution_time=300 in php ini file also and i have tested again it takes only 2 min.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone I found the solution. Actually what was an issue is jQuery AJAX timeout. I have increased AJAX timeout. Now I got to know my script is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by extending **max_execution_time** of your script.

if this does not work,then it might be chances that mysql connection time out happening and query stopped executing in between. (as you told there are large query executing)

Hence,please check **mysql.connect_timeout**  in your phpinfo and try extending it if required and then check.

Comment: where i should check in phpinfo(php.ini?) file or mysql.ini file? connection_timeout.

Comment: search mysql in your phpinfo and mysql.connect_timeout defined within that.

you can get phpinfo by adding <strong>phpinfo();</strong> line to your php script.

Comment: i have checked it. the master value=60 and local value=60. how much i should increase and where will i get the file to increase. i mean location.

Comment: I am not sure how much time your query executing taking.
you can run query in mysql and check time its taking to execution and can set accordingly at top of your file like and also update default_socket_timeout time in case its too low .

ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 14400);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 14400);

Once your query executing properly,you can change value as per requirement.

Answer (score -2):

Use This

Place this at the top of your PHP script it will increase your maximum execution time.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
```

[Click here for this function](http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-script-execution-time-limit-ini_set)

Comment: pretty sure that the question specifically states that they do not want a long running script..

Comment: Yes. What is the solution for this... Should i optimize my mysql qurey by adding index? if so please find my mysql query as follows, **SELECT status FROM globstats_graph WHERE moddate between '$init_1' and '$total_array[$i]' and Cname='$client' and IP='$ip' and Port='$port' and Variable='$var' and status REGEXP '^[0-9]+$|^ON$'**. Already variable column was indexed. For speed up process i have added index in cname column also. Could you suggest me that for which column i should add an index?